# Change SKAction.wait(forDuration: ) in sequence

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have this. It runs, but now I have to change the `forDuration: 10` in maybe `5`.
In the action sequence are 4 sprites that move their path for a given time. Once I run the sequence I can not change the `forDuration: 10`

Is the anybody out there, who can help me?

```
let s1_1 = SKAction.run{let unit = S1(); unit.gegnerSpeed = 100; unit.moveAlongPath(self.pfadGegner);self.addChild(unit)}
let s1_2 = SKAction.run{let unit = S1(); unit.gegnerSpeed = 80; unit.moveAlongPath(self.pfadGegner);self.addChild(unit)}


let action1 = SKAction.sequence([
                s1_1, SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
                s1_2, SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
                s1_1, SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
                s1_2, SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10)    ])
            let sequenz = SKAction.sequence([action1, SKAction.run {
                self.letzterGegnerLos = true
                }])
            run(SKAction.repeat(sequenz, count: 1))
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are running actions on your scene to run actions,  you should have your actions on specific nodes instead.  But that said,  once you assign a sequence, you can't change the actions inside of it as far as I am aware.  This means you have to remove the sequence, and assign a new sequence with a new wait duration.

Or do you?

In a case like yours, it is possible to manipulate the `speed` property of either the action, or the node.  To manipulate the speed of the action, you need to extract the action using `node.action(forKey:"key")`.  The only problem with this, is that you manipulate the speed on all the actions inside the sequence.

Instead, let's change the speed of the node.

To do this, I recommend using a variable to assign the speed:

```
let dSpeed = 1
let action1 = SKAction.sequence([

            s1_1,
            SKAction.run{[unowned self] in self.speed = dSpeed}, 
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
            SKAction.run{[unowned self] in self.speed = 1}, 
            s1_2,
            SKAction.run{[unowned self] in self.speed = dSpeed}, 
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
            SKAction.run{[unowned self] in self.speed = 1},
            s1_1, 
            SKAction.run{[unowned self] in self.speed = dSpeed},
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
            SKAction.run{[unowned self] in self.speed = 1},
            s1_2, 
            SKAction.run{[unowned self] in self.speed = dSpeed},
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
            SKAction.run{[unowned self] in self.speed = 1}    ])
        let sequenz = SKAction.sequence([action1, SKAction.run {
            self.letzterGegnerLos = true
            }])
        run(SKAction.repeat(sequenz, count: 1))
```

Of course, now we have a problem with the scene running fast.  This is why I am questioning why you are running things on your scene.

From the looks of your code,  you need a spawning node to spawn units.  Let's create that.

```
lazy var spawnNode = {
                         [unowned self] in
                         let node = SKNode()
                         self.addChild(node)
                         return node
                     }()
```

As soon as you access `spawnNode`, it will create it and add it to the scene for you.

Next, we set up your spawning functionality.

```
func spawn(_ speed:int)
{
    let unit = S1()
    unit.gegnerSpeed = speed
    unit.moveAlongPath(self.pfadGegner)
    self.addChild(unit)
}
```

Finally, let's set up your action

```
let s1_1 = SKAction.run{spawn(100)}
let s1_2 = SKAction.run{spawn(80)}
let dSpeed = 1
let action1 = SKAction.sequence([

            s1_1,
            SKAction.run{spawnNode.speed = dSpeed}, 
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
            SKAction.run{spawnNode.speed = 1}, 
            s1_2,
            SKAction.run{spawnNode.speed = dSpeed}, 
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
            SKAction.run{spawnNode.speed = 1},
            s1_1, 
            SKAction.run{spawnNode.speed = dSpeed},
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
            SKAction.run{spawnNode.speed = 1},
            s1_2, 
            SKAction.run{spawnNode.speed = dSpeed},
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
            SKAction.run{spawnNode.speed = 1}    ])
        let sequenz = SKAction.sequence([action1, SKAction.run {
            self.letzterGegnerLos = true
            }])
        run(SKAction.repeat(sequenz, count: 1))
```

Now, if we want the node to spawn twice as fast, we do `dSpeed = 2`. If we want the node to spawn twice as slow, we do `dSpeed = 0.5`.  By doing this in this fashion, we are not manipulating the speed of the scene in any way.

Just a note,  the reason I did the speed changes before and after a run block instead of 
 at the beginning and end of the sequence is in case you needed to do any animations.  The way the code is set up now,  run blocks fire immediately, so you can get away with setting dSpeed in the beginning, and 1 at the end.  But if for some reason, you place a move action right after you spawn a node,  that move action will use the speed of spawn node.  So if you are only going to do run blocks, then this is acceptable.

```
let action1 = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.run{spawnNode.speed = dSpeed}, 
        s1_1,     
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
        s1_2,
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
        s1_1, 
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
        s1_2, 
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10),
        SKAction.run{spawnNode.speed = 1}    ])
    let sequenz = SKAction.sequence([action1, SKAction.run {
        self.letzterGegnerLos = true
        }])
    run(SKAction.repeat(sequenz, count: 1))
```

Comment: Hello Knight0fDragon. Thank you very much for your answer. You make a lot of work. I will test it and give a feedback.. Thanks. Ralf.

Comment: Hello @Knight0fDragon. I think you don't understand me. Sorry for this, but my english is not the best. I dont want to Change the Speed of the gegnerSpeed. I want to Change the Duration in    SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10)

Comment: If English is a problem, then find a person to translate it better because I only speak English

Comment: Sorry, but as you may have noticed, I am a beginner. I unfortunately do not understand you. But thank you very much for your work.

Comment: Hallo, kann mir jemand weiterhelfen um die duration: 10 zu ändern, wenn die sequenz schon läuft?